# mysql: get data from two tables depends on id of the first table and the result in json

Tags: php, mysql, json, join

I've 2 tables, I want to get data from the first one depends on "id", and the data from second one depends on the "gid" that same as "id" from the first table, in JSON.

Example:

```
First Table: 
- - - - - - -
id  name
1   Aaron
2   Caleb
3   Albert
4   Ethan

Second Table:
- - - - - - -
id  gid image
1   1   http://.......image1.jpg
2   1   http://.......image2.jpg
3   2   http://.......image3.jpg
4   3   http://.......image4.jpg
5   3   http://.......image5.jpg
6   3   http://.......image6.jpg
```

I want the result when I request id=1, Something like this:

```
"names": [
    {

     "id": 1,

     "name": "Aaron"
          "images":[
             {
                "id" :1
                "url":http://.......image1.jpg
             },
             {
                "id" :2
                "url":http://.......image2.jpg
             }
       ]
   }
]
```

This some of my code:

```
$SqlInfo = "Select * from tabel1 where id='$id'";

$obj = json_decode($_GET["x"], false);
$stmt = $con->prepare($SqlInfo);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $obj->table, $obj->limit);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$outp = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

echo json_encode(array(
    'status' => 'Ok',
    'name' => $outp
    ));
```

to be more specific, my above code , bring json format for the first table, I want to insert the result of the second table in the same result of json (of the first table).
Thank you ...

Comment: I didn't find what i want, I need the result as the first post, Now, I can get the data in JSON format but I need to insert the list of the images that are from another table inside the main JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you  can use inner join to combine result from both table

```
$sql = "select 
           t2.gid,
           t2.id,
           t2.image,
           ti.name 
        from 
            second_table as t2
        join first_table as t1 on t2.gid = t1.id 
        where id='$id'           
       ";

$obj = json_decode($_GET["x"], false);
$stmt = $con->prepare($SqlInfo);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $obj->table, $obj->limit);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$outp = $result->fetch_all(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
/*PDO::FETCH_ASSOC return result in associative array */
$arr = array();
if(!empty($outp)){

    $i =1;/* this is used so that first table data can only be feed to array once*/

    foreach($outp as $val){
        if($i ==1){
            $arr['id'] = $val['gid'];
            $arr['name'] = $val['name'];
        }
        $tmp = array();
        $tmp['id'] = $val['gid'];
        $tmp['url'] = $val['image'];
        $arr['images'][] = $tmp;
        $i++;
        /*increment $i so that we cannot enter $val['name'] repeatedly*/ 
    }
}
$json_arr = array('status' => 'Ok','name' => $arr);
echo json_encode($json_arr);
```

Comment: Thank you so much , I changed some lines at the code, and now works good, But is there a way to get the information for all user like if I didn't use WHERE id=1 , Just used Select *. from table1.
so I'll get all users informations and thier images

Comment: @Fadi just remove `where id='$id'` in sql statement

Comment: it's gave me just the information of one user and his images

Comment: i replaced :  
  //$outp = $result->fetch_all(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


With : 
  $outp = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

Comment: before changed to  $outp = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);, always gives me null for all values.
And if I removed the werer id = '$id' , gives me the information of one person.

where is my wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need the result of first table to decode into Array.

```
$first_table = array(
    '0'=> ['id'=> 1, 'name' =>'Aaron' ],
    '1'=> ['id'=> 2, 'name' =>'Caleb' ],
    '2'=> ['id'=> 3, 'name' =>'Albert'],
    '3'=> ['id'=> 4, 'name' =>'Ethan' ]
    );

//create function to retrieve images by ID from Second Table 
function get_images($id)
{
$SqlInfo = "Select id, image as url from tabel2 where gid='$id'";
$stmt = $con->prepare($SqlInfo);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$outp = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    return $outp;
}   

// create a new object
$new_array=array();

//Loop first table
foreach ( $first_table as $key => $value){

$new_array[$value['name']]  = [
                                'name' => $value['name'],
                                'id' => $value['id'],
                                'images' => get_images($value['id']) // Get images from function
                               ];

}

$final = json_encode($new_array);
```

This was not tested, but solution should be in this direction